# Netsuite Rest API POST message attachments

Tags: netsuite, attachment, netsuite-rest-api

We are using Netsuite as our CRM application.
We already build an interface at our website to add messages to existing supportcases.
Im using the `REST API` and the `suiteQL API` to POST data to netsuite.
However we now want to expand this to add attachments to messages.

I did some research and found only these queries:

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE activity = '[supportcasenumber]' ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

This gives me the following result:

```
{
  "links": [],
  "attachments": "4729",
  "author": "-4",
  "authoremail": "test@company.com",
  "datetime": "18/12/2019",
  "emailed": "T",
  "entity": "375",
  "hasattachment": "T",
  "htmlmessage": "T",
  "id": "1512",
  "incoming": "T",
  "internalonly": "F",
  "lastmodifieddate": "18/12/2019",
  "message": "This is my message with attachment"
}
```

I took the attachment value and ran the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM file WHERE id = '4729'
```

Which gave me the following result:

```
{
    "links": [],
    "addtimestamptourl": "F",
    "createddate": "18/12/2019",
    "filesize": "5153",
    "filetype": "JPGIMAGE",
    "folder": "595",
    "hideinbundle": "F",
    "id": "4729",
    "iscompanywidereadaccess": "F",
    "isinactive": "F",
    "islink": "F",
    "isonline": "F",
    "lastmodifieddate": "18/12/2019",
    "name": "image001.jpg",
    "url": "/core/media/media.nl?id=4729&c=999999&h=BWjJpaxXKjlicRdbqD5FIxhsuBj7tFYwqzRcCwLuJs_760N4"
 }
```

I would like to be able to add an attachment to a new message.
I already do an post request to `/message` ([message endpoint documentation](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2021.2/index.html#/definitions/message))

There is nothing described on how to add an attachment with it, does someone know if its possible or how to do it?